# How to Retreive Balance

Tags: mysql, sql

[![PARTY BALANCE PICTURE 1 ][1]][1]

[![PARTY BALANCE PICTURE 2][2]][2]

Thank you Question Resolved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Jonny . . . I removed the Postgres tag because your question is explicitly about MySQL.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT customer, (sum(debit) - sum(credit)) as balance, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN credit > 0 THEN date END) as last_credit_date
FROM ledger l
GROUP BY customer;
```